# Error 1452 en MySql workbench foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

quiero crear una foreign key de una tabla ya creada usando alter table y add constraint pero al momento de hacerlo me sale error 1452. Ya intenté varias cosas y nada. Espero que me puedan ayudar. muchas gracias

```
create table if not exists clientes (
ClienteID int (22) auto_increment,
Nombre varchar(50),
Apellido varchar(50),
Direccion varchar(50),
Ciudad varchar(50),
Estado varchar(50),
CP int(11),
primary key(ClienteID)
);

insert into clientes values (null,'Leandro', 'Lopez', 'Arboledas', 'Oaxaca de J.', 'Oaxaca', 77230);
insert into clientes values (null,'Sofia', 'Martinez', 'Eucaliptos', 'Guadalajara', 'Jalisco', 81760);


create table if not exists Ordenes (
Orden int (22)  auto_increment,
ClienteID int(22),
LibroID int(11),
FechaOrden date,
primary key(Orden)
);

insert into Ordenes values (null, 123, 45, '2020-03-11');
insert into Ordenes values (null, 204, 525, '2020-04-11');

alter table Ordenes add constraint clientesfk foreign key (ClienteID) references clientes(ClienteID);
```

Comment: Que raro, a mí me sigue saliendo que esta mal la constraint foreign key.

Comment: El problema que tienes es que estas intentando crear el FK despues de insertar datos en la tabla Ordenes, debes crearlo con la tabla vacia.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás tratando de apuntar una FK sin saber los valores que tienen en la table referida. Para asegurar que los valores `123` y `204` son válidos debes indicarlos durante la inserción.

Por ejemplo, especifica los valores de la columna `ClienteID` durante la inserción de la primera tabla:

```
insert into clientes (ClienteID, Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Ciudad,Estado,CP)
values (123, 'Leandro', 'Lopez', 'Arboledas', 'Oaxaca de J.', 'Oaxaca', 77230);

insert into clientes (ClienteID, Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Ciudad,Estado,CP)
values (204, 'Sofia', 'Martinez', 'Eucaliptos', 'Guadalajara', 'Jalisco', 81760);
```

Luego, los insert en `Ordenes` van a funcionar correctamente.